# Always return a specified number of records Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a query that I always want to return 10 records for:

```
set rowcount 10
select row_number() over(order by count(*) desc) row_num
    ,hist_report_id
    ,max(rpt_report_name) report_name
from utility.dbo.tbl_report_history
join utility.dbo.tbl_report_definitions
    on hist_report_id = rpt_report_id
where hist_user_id = 1038
group by hist_report_id
```

Which works fine if I have 10 or more records. The problem is when there are less than 10 records, I still need to return the rownumber field with nulls in the report_id and report_name fields.

If there were only 7 records returned, the results should look like:

```
row_num report_id report_name
1       id1       name1
2       id2       name2
3       id3       name3
4       id4       name4
5       id5       name5
6       id6       name6
7       id7       name7
8       null      null
9       null      null
10      null      null
```

Any suggestions?

I am using SQL Server 2008

Comment: Sql server version? I guess  you need some kind of union with a temp table or table variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`count()` can never return less than zero... so just append 10 dummy rows with -1 in the count column via union

Also, don't use SET ROWCOUNT because it affects intermediate results

```
SELECT TOP 10
   row_number() over(order by TheCount desc) AS row_num,
   hist_report_id,
   report_name
FROM
    (
    select 
        ,count(*) AS TheCount
        ,hist_report_id
        ,max(rpt_report_name) AS report_name
    from 
       utility.dbo.tbl_report_history
       join 
       utility.dbo.tbl_report_definitions on hist_report_id = rpt_report_id
    where hist_user_id = 1038
    group by hist_report_id
    UNION ALL
    SELECT TOP 10
         -1, NULL, NULL
    FROM sys.columns
    ) T
```

Comment: Great! I was hoping to have a single statement solution, and this works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

```
with
/* Create 10 dummy rows using recursion */
RowSequence as (
    select 0 Idx
    union all
    select RowSequence.Idx+1 Idx from RowSequence where RowSequence.Idx+1<10
    ),
/* Your Query */
YourQuery as(
    select row_number() over(order by count(*) desc) row_num
        ,hist_report_id
        ,max(rpt_report_name) report_name
    from utility.dbo.tbl_report_history
    join utility.dbo.tbl_report_definitions
        on hist_report_id = rpt_report_id
    where hist_user_id = 1038
    group by hist_report_id
    )
/* Now all together */
select top 10 * from (
    select * from YourQuery
    union all
    select null, null, null from RowSequence
    ) a
/* To avoid the recursion maximum level 100 */
option (maxrecursion 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way that I recall:

1. `Insert` the `select result` in a `#temptable`
2. `While count(*) < 10` `insert` row `into #temptable`

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using a TVF to return for you a set of numbers that you could outer join with:

```
CREATE FUNCTION SetOfValues (@beginningAt int, @endingAt int, @step int = 1)
RETURNS 
    @result TABLE (value int )
AS BEGIN
    declare @counter int set @counter = @beginningAt
    while(@counter<=@endingAt)
    begin
        insert into @result values(@counter)
        set @counter = @counter + @step
    end 
RETURN 
END
GO

-- USAGE
with cte as (
    select row_number() over (order by hist_report_Id) as row_num,
    hist_report_Id, report_name
    from tbl_report_history join tbl_report_definitions on hist_report_Id = rpt_reportId)
select value, hist_reportId, report_name 
from dbo.SetOfValues(1,10,1) as t on t.value = cte.row_num
```